# Remove automatic p tag in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Before all, I've searched a way to done this. But it still occure.

So I use the theme Creative, I've got a contact form, done with Contact Form 7. And to display it in the right place, it need to be placed in a widget aera.

I've inserted the shortcode of the form in a text widget, in a widget for shortcode, and also in a widget for Contact Form 7.

For every case, the inputs and label are wrapped into `p` tag, and it brake the submit function, I guess.

So I've tried a fiew things to disable this function.

In my function.php, at the end :

```
//* Disable automatic p tag insertion
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');
add_filter( 'the_content', 'disable_wpautop_cpt', 0 );
function disable_wpautop_cpt( $content ) {
  'your_cpt_slug' === get_post_type() && remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
return $content;
}
```

In my wp-config.php, at the end too :

```
/** Disable automatic p tag insertion */
define( 'WPCF7_AUTOP', false );
```

And more, I added a plugin to disable this function of WP on the page where the form is.

But the tags are still there. Help

***EDIT : Added screen.***

[Form code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNjUq.png)

[HTML in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoINl.png)

Comment: In contact form 7 you want to remove p tag. to do this you just need to remove p tag from the From section of the contact form 7

Comment: @AoNoLoki -- Did you ever find a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your functions.php file

```
 function reformat_auto_p_tags($content) {
        $new_content = '';
        $pattern_full = '{(\[raw\].*?\[/raw\])}is';
        $pattern_contents = '{\[raw\](.*?)\[/raw\]}is';
        $pieces = preg_split($pattern_full, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
            if (preg_match($pattern_contents, $piece, $matches)) {
                $new_content .= $matches[1];
            } else {
                $new_content .= wptexturize(wpautop($piece));
            }
        }

        return $new_content;
    }

    remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
    remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');

    add_filter('the_content', 'reformat_auto_p_tags', 99);
    add_filter('widget_text', 'reformat_auto_p_tags', 99);
```

Then on your post editor wrap your contact form 7 shortcode with raw shortcode
e.g.

```
[raw][contact-form-7 id="1" title="Contact Us"][/raw]
```

Comment: I'm gonna add a screen of the <code>p</code> tag position, and of the form

Comment: There's no p tag in my form, but WordPress add them when the code is displayed

Comment: can you please share your site to check me

Comment: The website is currently in dev and so not published yet, sorry

Comment: Ain't working, even with all the solution active the p tag are added

Answer (score 0):

Use wpautop filter for remove auto p tags in content or the_excerpt

```
<?php wpautop( $foo, $br ); ?>
```

Example:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

More Ref : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use JS. Above code will help you to remove all empty p tag from the page

```
jQuery('p:empty').remove();
```